# HUGO + GitHub Pages: How to set up subdomain

Tags: subdomain, github-pages, hugo, static-site, hugo-shortcode

I have a github repository that I want to add my hugo site to. From the docs folder in my repository I can run github pages.

Therefore, I have changed my `publishDir` parameter in the hugo config to `docs`.

```
publishDir = "docs"
```

Now when I build hugo it ouputs everything in the docs folder which is great, the issue is running a subdomain from there.

How do I get a subdomain on hugo that is generated into my docs folder that acts like a subdomain on github pages?

I know I would need to use a CNAME and then tell it to say `/docs/subdomain` is actually `subdomain.site.com`

but I am not sure how to set that up in HUGO. and where do I put the subdomain folder? in the static folder so it would be `theme_name/static/subdomain` which would ouput into the docs like `docs/subdomain`?

If this is the way, can I use all the parameters and shortcodes in my static folder?

Also, if I need to create 2 hugo installations, one for the main site and one for the subdomain site, is their a way to share site params, configs,  static files and layout files etc… ?

Comment: Shouldn't you just make subdomain.site.com your `baseURL` in your Hugo project?
And site.com as `baseURL` in your other Hugo project (if it is one)? 
If I were you, I would split your Hugo project in two unrelated repositories: the project itself, and the built site. It is not clear from your question, what do you want to expose - the source code of the project, the site only, or two sites, or etc...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a custom script to create two different builds and then

Add a CNAME file to your project's repository. The content of this file must be a single line specifying the bare subdomain for your project's custom subdomain (e.g. pjname.mydomain.com).
In your DNS provider's settings, create a new CNAME record that points project name to either the root (usually denoted by @), if you have previously set up an apex domain, or to myusername.github.io if you've set up a custom subdomain. It should look something like this:

Answer (score 0):

If you have two sites that you want to serve separately under two domains/subdomains (or even subpath), it's better that you create two different repositories for that.

In your username.github.io repository, you are using the "docs" folder to serve your site. However, this procedure will not work for other repositories. To serve from other repositories, name the repo whatever you like and create a "gh-pages" branch on it. The branch root must contain the entire site. You can access this site using **username.github.io/your-repo-name/**.

In this new repo you can add a CNAME. Hope this works. I did almost the same thing, except that I used subpaths instead of subdomains. Here's my main profile [rafed.github.io](https://rafed.github.io/) and my blog [rafed.github.io/devra/](https://rafed.github.io/devra/)